# Excel: Across spreadsheets data lookup and display

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, spreadsheet, lookup, display

Search Table/Sheet

[image]

Tables each on different sheets
[image]

Picture 1 is what I want to be the search sheet,I would like a drop down list for each heading(Which I can do), but I'm struggling to display all the data from different sheets. Each sheet has the same layout and headings but different data stored. The data cannot be in a table as it is imported from the web. When the cell under "Name" (which will have a drop down of all the names) has lets say "John" selected then it will display the data across all sheets of "John" so it will display:

```
  - John | Manchester| 32 | 131| 1234| 123 | Money
  - John | Manchester| 32 | 1  |23213| 423 | Debt
  - John |Manchester |234 |34  | 23  |  2  | Income
```

And when I Choose Income in the (Sheet drop down list) it will 
display:

```
 - Tim |London    |34   |45 |435|22134|Income
 - Dave|Scotland  | 34  |23 |234|42   |Income
 - Jake|Walse     | 3   |4  |32 |566  |Income
 - John|Manchester| 234 |34 |23 |2    |Income
 -     |          |     |   |   |     |Income
 -     |          |     |   |   |     |Income
```

This is the best I can explain it, there are 60+ sheets on the real document this is just an example and as you can see the data is not in the same order or not at all for some people. 
I'm not sure if it's possible? Any help or a point in a direction to what I could try with a little research would be great. Wouldn't say I'm an expert in excel but I've tried a few things and nothing has worked.

Comment: This is possible, but with 60+ sheets it's not really feasible to do this with formulas, and I would instead recommend VBA.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried VLookup and Match, few others but cant remember. I was going to try tables but it doesn't allow me to make a table with imported info. Would VBA be complicated to do? As I'm not too experienced with Excel and never tried VBA

Comment: I would not recommend this as a first project for somebody who's never touched VBA before.  It's not super complicated, but would require loops and a worksheet_change event which does make it a much more complicated project.  Unfortunately this isn't a "code for me" site, so it may be in your best interest to see if you have a coworker that can do this.  If you're set on learning VBA to do this on your own, I recommend googling "Excel VBA loop through sheets" and "Excel VBA Worksheet_Change event" and see if you can piece something together. We can help you with specific problems you encounter

Comment: Also, in order to open the VBE (Visual Basic Editor) within Excel, press Alt+F11.  Because you need a worksheet_change event, double-click on the worksheet (within the VBE) that will have the drop-downs you're using for filtering.  That will bring up that sheet's code module

Comment: And of course, always create a copy of the workbook so that if anything goes horribly wrong, you'll still have the original as a backup (and can just make another copy if necessary).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a go.